# How to disable specific dates on DatePickerIOS and DatePickerAndroid?

Tags: javascript, react-native, datepicker

I have a calendar on react-native, and I need it to have some dates disabled (not choosable by user, i.e. every Tuesday and Friday). 
I don't see such options in docs

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerandroid.html

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerios.html

Is there a way to do that?

`"react-native": "0.55.2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this

```
<DatePickerIOS
      date={this.state.chosenDate}
      onDateChange={(date) => {
        if(date.getDay() != '2' || date.getDay() != '5')  {
          this.setState({chosenDate: newDate})
        }
        else {
          this.setState({error:'you can not select this date ...'})
        }

      }}
    />
```

Comment: Amazing workaround! I actually don't need to show any message to the user, so guessing that  I'd just  change `state.chosenDate` to the nearest available. Thanks!

Comment: If it is working for you then please, accept as correct one

Comment: Yeah, sure. Don't you know how would it be for DatePickerAndroid?

Comment: thanks, I have no more about DatePickerAndroid,  but I think you need to add some logic in  DatePickerAndroid.open function